# Why isn't my sign-in form working in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very rudimentary sign-in form where the user enters in his/her name (First Last).

Here is the code in ERB for the form:

```
<%= form_for :current_user, url: { :controller => 'application', :action=>'current_user' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'First Last', :id => 'currentUser' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the action current_user:

```
def current_user
  @current_user = User.find_by_name(params[:current_user][:name])
  redirect_to '/calendar'
end
```

And here is it's route

```
match 'calendar/signin', to: 'application#current_user', via: 'post'
```

The form works, I tested it by placing a debugger in the current_user action. When I typed in `params` it returned the user's name that I had entered in as it should have. But once it went back to the `/calendar` view @current_user became undefined again. Should I be using something rather than `redirect_to '/calendar'`? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should be calling `redirect_to` with the appropriate path method, for example:

```
redirect_to calendar_path
```

Using a literal URL defeats the purpose of the routing system. You'll need to track down and change all instances of `/calendar` to something else should that ever change. With the routing method, you can change the presentation, the user-facing URL, from the implementation.

Likewise, you should be using the same path notation in your `url` argument to `form_for`. Calling it by controller and action is the older way of doing it and isn't without its share of problems, as the URL it uses is not always what you'd prefer.

Your `current_user` method only assigns `@current_user` if it's called, and your form requires `@current_user` to be defined in advance. If for some reason it isn't called, your form won't work, there's no object. `:current_user` is a reference to `@current_user` in the context of the view, where the view automatically inherits instance variables from the controller.

Normally you'd have a method like this:

```
def load_current_user
  @current_user = User.find_by(name: ...)
end
```

Then you trigger this to load all the time:

```
before_filter :load_current_user
```

Normally I create a controller class that requires logins and all the "log-in only" controllers inherit from it. That way you should be reasonably assured you don't have pages that are not properly restricted.

Obviously you'd want to skip this on pages that don't require a login, for example your session controller where you log in:

```
skip_before_filter :load_current_user, only: [ :new, :create ]
```

Comment: Thank you, you're response was very informative. It seems to me that the issue is that @current_user can't be called without calling the current_user method. So, the reason that the user's information isn't showing up is because I'm not calling the method. So, what would you recommend as a solution for this? Should I split it into two separate methods?

Comment: My recommendation here is to trigger that method in a `before_filter` so you can be assured it's set properly.